# Tomcat7 breaking request parameter behaviour from Tomcat5.5 and Struts1.1?

Tags: request, tomcat7, struts-1, http-request-parameters

I have a link which points to my servlet (Struts 1.1 App).

```
http://myserver.com/app/preview.do;jsessionid=1234567;p1=test;filename=/page2.htm
```

All was working fine in Tomcat5.5 and jdk1.6, but now with tomcat7 and jdk7, it does not work anymore. Tomcat now sends 404 error, because

```
/app/preview.do;jsessionid=1234567;p1=test;filename=/page2.htm" could not be found on server
```

So it tries to find the file page2.htm in path.

Does anybody know how to configure Tomcat to get it work again?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with tomcat but I assume you will be able to fix this by adding an entry to whatever tomcat uses as a search path. What have you tried?

Comment: This is exactly what I do not know: How do I configure what tomcat uses as searchpath. :)